# Moving CakePhp installation from internal dev server to local web server

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I have setup CakePhp inside one of my application and able to run my application's scaffolding code on the internal development server at port 8765.

Now i want to make use of my local web apache web server.

I checked the documentation of CakePhp. Its mentioned like below

*you should be able to move your CakePHP install (including the
hidden files) inside your webserver’s document root. You should then be able to point your web-browser at
the directory you moved the files into and see your application in action.*

I am using Apache server so my document root is htdocs and can be configured through httpd.conf.

Now according to the above statement i have below queries

(a) What are the cakephp install files. I have a project created with all cakephp files.

(b) My project is already under htdocs which itself contains all the cakephp files. Where do i point my document root to ?

(c) How do i detach my application code with the cake php install files ?

Regards,

Saurav

Comment: have you tried opening a browser and looking at `http://localhost` or similar? `How do I detach my application code` - what does this mean?

Comment: yes so my webserver is running at localhost and my internal server is running at localhost:8765....

Comment: Great news.  
have you tried opening a browser and looking at `http://localhost` or similar?

Comment: ok..probably i was not clear at explaining...my cakephp is installed alongwith my scaffolding code for my application inside a folder...that folder is inside htdocs (which is the document root of Apache server)...now when i run my apache server which is on localhost:80...it is opening the bitnami homepage...localhost/myapp is opening the cakephp home page (Which is correct)...now i want to access the resource of the scaffoling code

Comment: ok, what does `http://localhost/myapp/mycontrollername` show you? Are you only asking what url to use to access a controller?

Comment: thanks a lot @AD7six...precisely i was looking for this...i must say i haven't read the cakephp documentation with detail